# Extract metadata from SWF file, preferably using Java

Tags: metadata, apache-tika, exiftool

I have been trying to extract metadata from Apache tika for a flash file and got the following output.

```
D:\DocumentServiceProject\FileTypes>java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar  -j MfS.swf
{ "Content-Length":1328282,
"Content-Type":"application/x-shockwave-flash",
"resourceName":"MfS.swf" }
```

Unhappy with what I got, I looked into Exiftool and am quite happy to see what i got.

```
D:\DocumentServiceProject\FileTypes>exiftool -j MfS.swf
[{
  "SourceFile": "MfS.swf",
  "ExifToolVersion": 9.58,
  "FileName": "MfS.swf",
  "Directory": ".",
  "FileSize": "1297 kB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2014:04:21 13:28:27+05:30",
  "FileAccessDate": "2014:04:21 13:32:06+05:30",
  "FileCreateDate": "2014:04:21 13:24:47+05:30",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-rw-rw-",
  "FileType": "SWF",
  "MIMEType": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
  "FlashVersion": 10,
  "Compressed": true,
  "ImageWidth": 1024,
  "ImageHeight": 768,
  "FrameRate": 24,
  "FrameCount": 2,
  "Duration": "0.08 s",
  "FileAttributes": "UseNetwork, ActionScript3, HasMetadata",
  "Format": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
  "Title": "Vendor Portal Flex",
  "Language": "en_US",
  "Date": "Mon Apr 21 13:28:09 IST 2014",
  "ImageSize": "1024x768"
}]
```

Is there a way Apache Tika can help me get these metadata. I have other movie extension to process too but having very same issue thus not trying to replicate all file type in this question.

Comment: I stumbled upon this(http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/exiftool-enhanced-java-integration-for-exiftool/) but not seeing any traces of this in maven repository

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/P_W999/j-exiftool/wiki/Home seems to be the answer but not in maven repository

Comment: There's optional support in Apache Tika for calling ExifTool - see [Tika-774](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-774) and [this github project](https://github.com/Alfresco/tika-exiftool). What happens if you enable that, then add `application/x-shockwave-flash` to the mimetypes list for that?

Comment: Great, Hope this can be released to maven but from the code it looks like it will be released with 1.6.

Comment: Got this at https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/apache/tika/tika-exiftool/

Comment: https://github.com/Alfresco/tika-exiftool , 
 
bitbucket.org/P_W999/j-exiftool/wiki/Home and thebuzzmedia/exiftool all of them are very concentrated only on the image files

Comment: They all use exiftool though, so if what you want is to use exiftool, you just need to tweak them to activate for your video + ensure the right mappings are there